# How to deserialize json to nested custom map via gson?

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I have the following json

```
{
  "id": "1111",
  "match": {
    "username1": {
      "id": "1234",
      "name": "alex"
    },
    "username2": {
      "id": "5678",
      "name": "munch"
    }
  }
}
```

To deserialize it, I have the following data model class.

```
class json{
    String id;
    Match match;
}

class Match {  
  private Map<String,Profile> profiles  
}

class Profile{
    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

I am not getting any deserialization error when I am using gson but the
`profiles` variable is coming as null.
This is how I am deserializing.
 `var json = gson.fromJson(data,json.class)`

inside the `match` object there can be a dynamic number of usernames not just two . Why am I getting `profile` object as null and how can I correctly populate it?

Making changes to json is the last resort here. I can make any other required changes.

Comment: Do you have any setters in `Profile`?

Comment: @JoãoDias Yeah, I do have the standard getters and setters .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is your model. You don't need `Match` because `profiles` does not really exist in your JSON. You just `json` (this one with small changes) and `Profile`:

```java
class json{
    String id;
    Map<String,Profile> match;
}
```

This will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! worked like a charm.

Comment: You are welcome ;)